# How to get value of a particular cell in gridview i and pass it to db as a parameter in c#?

Tags: c#, gridview

i m using C#, i am having problem in retrieving value of particular cell in gridview. the scenario is, there is a list of jobs shown in my grid. Coloumns are job_id, and job_title. I am populating my grid from database, so the grid shows a list of jobs available. and client can click on job_title, which is a hyperlink (

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataKeys Property

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can embedd job_id in hyperlink - hyperlink can be part of you database (one extra column) or created when you are populating your grid with data from database.